# Transactions in Entity Framework vs. NHibernate

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate

Having used NHibernate for quite a while, I'm now learning Entity Framework.  In NHibernate, for each ISession instance I instantiated a single database transaction using ISession.BeginTransaction. In Entity Framework, how would I achieve the same effect of one transaction per context?

Answer (score 0):

An ISession doesn't strictly correspond to a database transaction in nHibernate, however it does have an implicit transaction built in you can see more here: [NHProf about implicit transactions](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions).

In Entity Framework a transaction is started implicit when you call SaveChanges, you can read more about that in [this article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx)

To have an explicit transaction in Entity Framework you use TransactionScope or BeginTransaction on the EntityConnection.

The easiest way is to use TransactionScope like this:

```
using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()){
    context.SaveChanges();
    //Do more work with this or another context
    context.SaveChanges();
    tran.Complete();
    //Or alternatively don't call Complete and because of the using block Dispose on tran will be 
    //called causing an Rollback
}
```

Comment: I checked my code and you're right about NHibernate, so I clarified my question.  Please provide some sample code regarding EF.

Comment: I modified my answer to include an example of using TransactionScope